# Choosing a model

Tags: forecasting, cross-validation, predictive-models, arima, validation

I am working on a sales forecast right now and I have created 4 models but I am unsure which one to use.

I have 17 Quarters of data(4 Full years + 1 QTR) and I am only looking to forecast 2 quarters into the future at maximum. My data is also very seasonal.

Here are some of the summary statistics I got for each model I ran.

[image]

Which model makes sense to choose given my situation?

My instinct is to go with the the Arima model because it has the lowest AIC but I am not super well versed in model validation and would like to hear others thoughts.

Comment: Welcome Larn, 1) are the various error estimates based on training or test data? 2) do you have any theory to inform which model you suspect would be correct?

Comment: It is all based on training data. I am not really sure how to answer your second question sorry.

Comment: Make 4 graph. Then ask you 4 time the question : "What will be the impact of an error on the real business ?" Finally, compare the indicators. But this option should be the last resort.